# Allow access to QuickSight templates from a different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have created a template in my AWS account and have been trying to update the template permissions to allow access from another account. I'm failing to find any relevant documentation as to what actions are applicable to a QuickSight template.

Can anyone share any insight on this? I have no idea how to move from here.

Comment: I have facing the same problem. Can you please tell me a way in which I can contact you ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please contact me on my LinkedIn  https://www.linkedin.com/in/a-b-714209186/        I am hopelessly stuck on this problem for a month now and it is crucial to the completion of my internship project. Therefore, I would be highly grateful to you if you can help...Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While updating the template permissions to provide cross account access to template you need to use IAM ARN of an account root in the principal instead of an individual user.

Please try using the CLI and access policy below and suggest with the observations :

```
aws quicksight update-template-permissions --aws-account-id <aws account ID> --template-id <Template Id> --grant-permissions file://TemplatePermission.json --profile default
```

Contents of Templatepermission.json are as follows:

```
[
{
"Principal": "arn:aws:iam::<aws account ID>:root",
"Actions": ["quicksight:UpdateTemplatePermissions","quicksight:DescribeTemplate"]
}
```

Once you have shared the template with the other account you will be able to create a dashboard with the template using the following steps.

To create a dashboard in account B using template in account A or B use create-dashboard CLI.

```
aws quicksight create-dashboard --aws-account-id <Account ID> --dashboard-id <any ID> --name <any dashboard name> --source-entity file://DashboardFromTemplate.json
```

content of DashboardFromTemplate.json file are as below:

```
{
"SourceTemplate": {
"DataSetReferences": [
{
"DataSetPlaceholder": "placeholder", 
"DataSetArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:<Account A ID>:dataset/<Dataset ID>"
}
],
"Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:<Account ID>:template/<Template ID>"
}
}
```

Note that the 'DataSetPlaceholder' value needs to match the Data set placeholder used to create the Template. This can be found by executing this in the account the template was created in.

```
aws quicksight describe-template --aws-account-id <Account ID where the template is created> --template-id <Template ID>
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks much

Comment: Any idea about how this can be achieved within the same account but across different regions?

Comment: @RitikKumar Did you find anything about how to do it across regions?

Comment: Let's say I have created a template in an account A and now I want to use the  same template for other users as well. Also I have pushed the dataset in the user's account . So now when I call create dashboard API , then i) what should be the account ID ? ii) and what should be the dataset ARN ? . Also the generated dataset ARN should belong to the user's account or the account in which the template was created?

Comment: @Bokko In your example where you create the dashboard in account B, should the `DataSetArn` be pointing to the data set in account B?  In your example, you are pointing to `<Account A ID>`